# ASP .NET MVC RAZOR | Get value of @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make a small table, which can set the amount of columns through an "input field". I generated the the input field by following code (+ button):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Columns.Count, new { @class = "text-center control-form", @id = "countID" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Columns.Count)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreateTable", "Home", new { count = VARIABLEHERE })'">Update</button>
```

I basically try to set the input of the `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Columns.Count ..` as parameter of the function, executed by the button.

 I tried using `@Model.Columns.Count`, but that's not working, because the count doesn't change through the input field.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Razor runs on the server. As soon as you see the page rendered, nothing will be updated anymore. You need JavaScript for what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try put inside a form (using or not the html razor helper):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null){ your code... }
```

Button should be of *submit* type..